# R Error: package 'mvtnorm' required by 'multcomp' could not be found

Tags: r, installation

I need to install the package `multcomp`. After installing the package (`install.packages("multcomp")`) I get the message:

```
package ‘zoo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘mvtnorm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘TH.data’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘sandwich’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘multcomp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\kbn982\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwbLdqW\downloaded_packages
```

But when I load the library an error message appears:

> Error: package 'mvtnorm' required by 'multcomp' could not be found .

I also tried to change the library location installing it into another path.
But I don't have a clue why I get this message.

Comment: Install package `mvtnorm` also.

Comment: Thank you Pascal, for the suggestion, but it doesn´t work.

Comment: I get the same error message (Error: package 'mvtnorm' required by 'multcomp' could not be found) even after installing mvtnorm, as you suggested.

Comment: Where are located `multcomp` and `mvtnorm` packages?

Comment: The problem seems to be related to the fact that I am connected to a network drive. I will try to solve it! Thank you for your time, Pascal!