# R Error: package ‘lme4’ required by ‘pbkrtest’ could not be found

Tags: r, installation-package, revolution-r

My question is related to the post: [R Error: package 'mvtnorm' required by 'multcomp' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839144/r-error-package-mvtnorm-required-by-multcomp-could-not-be-found)

I'm using Revolution R and I'm trying to install the `pbkrtest` package and I have already installed the `lme4` package. However, during installation of `pbkrtest`, R doesn't seem to be able to find `lme4`. Any idea why? The same issue has popped up with a few other packages and dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I performed this exact operation last week without issue. I don't have admin rights, and so had to save the file to my user directory.  Here is the process I used:

Windows 7, revo R 3.2.3

construct a directory on my desktop, open R:

```
setwd(<path to my new folder>)
download.packages(<myPackages>, destdir=getwd(), type="win.binary")
install.packages(list.files(), repos=NULL, type="win.binary", lib=Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER"))
```

Notes:
* The reason I used `download.packages()` is to build an in-house repository for work.
* A few of the (~4 of 300) packages did not download, so I had to download them manually.
* This is my first experience with revo R, specifying type was never necessary in vanilla R, but seemed necessary here.

Comment: I've installed the packages in my own folder and then set `.libPaths('/path/to/my/folder')`. So I have full read/write permissions on this folder. But I still get that problem where it can't find the required prerequisite package.

Comment: If you can, try to save them in the default user folder: `lib=Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER")` as in the above code. This almost certainly will fix the issue.